# jQuery validation plugin & select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I use jQuery validation plugin from [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). Is there a way to check if the field is NOT equal to some string?
I have a select element looking like this:

```
<select id="school_admin" name="school">
   <option value="selector">Select...</option>
   <option value="UDSM">University of Dar Es Salaam</option>
   <option value="ARU">Ardhi University</option>
   <option value="IFM">Institute of Finance Management</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, first option is 'Select...' and I need to check on submit that it's not set to this first item, but to some another actual option. How can I do that quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just change the default option value to blank and leverage the metadata support by declaring a class of required on the select. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TdRV2/)

Answer (score 1):

A better way of coding your select might be to use an `optgroup`:

```
<select id="school_admin" name="school">
    <optgroup label="Select a school...">
        <option value="selector">Select...</option>
        <option value="UDSM">University of Dar Es Salaam</option>
        <option value="ARU">Ardhi University</option>
        <option value="IFM">Institute of Finance Management</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

The 'select' label is then not selectable.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/optgroup

Comment: I think it's a good solution and I undoubtedly will use it in another application  but I need to make that first item visible, not the first item in schools list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#item").html() != "string" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you leave **Select...**'s value empty `value=""` then simply

```
if ( ( sel = $('#school_admin').val() ).length ) { ... }
else { .. }
```

Never used the actual plugin, so you should be able to make it work with its own api

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the select element, and see if it matches the first one.

```
if ($('#school_admin').val() != 'selector') {
    //Doesn't equal the first one, do your thing
}
```